# Is there a way to programmatically restart an azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azureportal

I have an Azure function running on a timer every few minutes that after a varied amount of time of running will begin to fail every time it runs because of an external API and hitting the restart button manually in the azure portal fixes the problem and the job works again.

Is there a way to either get an azure function to restart itself or have something externally restart an azure function via a web hook or API request or running on a timer

I have tried using Azures API Management service which can be used to restart other kinds of app services in azure but it turns out there is no functionality in the API to request a restart of an azure function, Also looked into power shell and it seems to be the same problem you can restart different app services but not azure functions

i have tried working with the API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/
Example API request where you can list functions within an azure function 
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/functions?api-version=2016-08-01

but there is no functionality to restart an azure function from what i have researched

Basically i want to Restart the Azure function as if i was to hit this button 
[Azure functions manual stop/start and restart buttons in azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daHrM.png)

because there is a case where the job gets into a bad state every time it runs because of an external API i have no control over and hitting restart manually gets the job going again

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Why do you need to explicitly restart an Azure Function app?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by restart? The function will 'start' each time you make the HTTP call. Do you mean to ask about updating the function code?

Comment: edited the question to give more information required

Comment: @Aurelius nowadays that is is easy to accomplish. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/) for that:

```
az functionapp restart --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

You can confirm it does the same as the manual restart button on the portal by inspecting the [Activity Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log?tabs=powershell) of the function:

[image]

> Also looked into power shell and it seems to be the same problem you can restart different app services but not azure functions

Nowaday this is possible using PowerShell:

```
Get-AzFunctionApp -Name MyAppName -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName | Restart-AzFunctionApp -Force
```

(You could create a PowerShell Azure Function if you want to automate things)

Answer (score 5):

Another way to restart your function is by using the "watchDirectories" setting in the host.json file. If your host.json looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "watchDirectories": [ "Toggle" ]
}
```

You could toggle a restart by using following statement in a function:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:/home/site/wwwroot/Toggle/restart.conf", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Looking at the logs, the function reloads as it has detected the file change in the directory:

```
Watched directory change of type 'Changed' detected for 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\Toggle\restart.conf'  
Host configuration has changed. Signaling restart
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work when the function code's folder is write protected: WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE application setting variable set to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Azure functions by their nature are called upon an event. That may be a timer, a trigger or invocation like a HTTP event. They cannot be restarted per se, i.e. if you a function throws and exception, you cannot find the specific instance and re-run it using the out of the box functionality.

However, you can engineer your way to a more reliable solution:

1. Replay the event that invoked the function (i.e. kick it off again)
2. For non-sensitive data, log the payload of the function and create a another function that can be called on demand to re-run it. I.e. you create a proxy to "re-invoke" the function.
3. Harden your code by implementing a retry policy. See [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).
4. Add a service bus in to your architecture. Have a simple function to write the call payload to a message bus payload. Have another function to pick up the payload and process it more extensively where there may be unreliable integrations etc). That way if the call fails you can abandon and dead letter failures for later reprocessing.
5. Consider using [Durable Function Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-concepts) and leveraging the durable patterns, these can help make your functions code more robust and manage state.

Comment: This is beside the point. For example I need to restart functions because it looks like every http trigger creates a new function rather then reusing the existing ones, that never die, and in this way they end up "eating" all available database connections never releasing them.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try below ARM API. Since Azure function also fall under App service category, sometimes this may be helpful, 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/restart