# Unload assemblies after azure function is executed

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have an azure function which performs an grpc call to a server (.net 6). Inside the function I dynamically load an assembly (dynamically generated) which unfortunately is not unloaded after the function finishes  because of a leak inside a 3-rd party library.
Can I somehow kill the function process after execution?.. so next time I execute the function I can load again the correct assembly?

Comment: You don't have control over how the *next* execution of your function will be handled by Azure, will it be in same host, or process space, so you should not ideally be implementing such behavior - either ways loading same assembly again would not throw any errors, are you facing that issue?

Comment: We a are developing a test application. We dynamically generate client code based on user choices and the we execute methods from the generated code. So the assembly is generated, loaded dynamically  and then we execute methods from assembly. The problem we face is that we can't always unload  the assembly in order to load another generated one. I was thinking to other strategies... How to make sure I can kill the entire process?

Comment: In this scenario, if you name the assembly dynamically, then it will not be a concern to forcibly kill the entire process to load the next generated assembly.

Comment: True, but the old assembly will not stay loaded in memory and after 100 executions I don't have memory available?

Comment: If you are not deploying from zip package, then you could use the [watchDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#watched-directories) setting in host.json to trigger a restart of your function app. This is also suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57587132/14973743), try if it works for you.