# What is the difference between watchDirectories and watchFiles in azure-functions host.json?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Some code I help maintain uses the `watchDirectories` method below to restart the app, using the method suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57587132/7157204).

Referring from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json, are `watchDirectories` and `watchFiles` effectively the same thing -- just to restart the app? Besides the obvious (a file vs a directory), what other differences are there? The linked documentation for `watchDirectories` mentions it is watching for changes to assemblies.

> watchDirectories
>
> A set of [shared code directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#watched-directories) that should be monitored for changes. Ensures that when code in these directories is changed, the changes are picked up by your functions.
>
> ```
> {
>     "watchDirectories": [ "Shared" ]
> }
> ```

> watchFiles
>
> An array of one or more names of files that are monitored for changes that require your app to restart. This guarantees that when code in these files are changed, the updates are picked up by your functions.
>
> ```
> {
>     "watchFiles": [ "myFile.txt" ]
> }
> ```

Comment: To keep an eye on directories containing shared code, use the watchDirectories option. When code (such as assemblies, DLLs, or other shared components) in these directories is changed, the Azure Functions runtime will detect the changes, apply them to your functions, and restart the application. according to the SO thread answer you shared The Azure Functions runtime evaluates the configuration change indicated by the "watchDirectories" setting and starts the function app restart.

Comment: The watchFiles setting, on the other hand, is used to keep an eye on particular files. The Azure Functions runtime will cause an app restart to take effect when the contents of the specified files are changed. This is frequently used when changing configuration files or other important files and needing the changes to take effect right away.

Comment: The linked documentation for watchDirectories mentions it is watching for changes to assemblies. >> Yes, WatchDirectories will check if there's any changes in the packages in package.json for javascript based function app or python packages in python based function aps or DLL's, assemblies and apply those changes to the Function app automatically and restart the app.

Comment: A restart of the function app can be caused by changing a file in the watched directory by using the "watchDirectories" setting. It acts as an alternative method of accomplishing the same goal as the watchFiles setting, which proactively checks specific files for modifications that necessitate app restarts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are `watchDirectories` and `watchFiles` effectively the same thing --just to restart the app? Besides the obvious (a file vs a directory), what other differences are there? The linked documentation for
> `watchDirectories` mentions it is watching for changes to assemblies.

**The Difference:- The watchDirectories and watchFiles properties in the host.json file are used to keep track of code changes and restart the app when necessary. In contrast to watchFiles, which tracks changes to one or more unique files, watchDirectories keeps track of changes to a group of shared code directories, Assemblies, packages, DLL's etc. The Function app will be restarted in order to pick those changes and get updated.**

- WatchDirectories is implemented To keep an eye on directories containing shared code. When code  (such as assemblies, DLLs, packages or other shared components) in
  -these directories is changed, the Azure Functions runtime will detect the changes, apply them to your functions, and restart the application. According to the [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127675/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-restart-an-azure-function/57587132#57587132) you shared The Azure Functions runtime evaluates the configuration change indicated by the "watchDirectories" setting and starts the function app restart.
- WatchFiles on the other hand, is used to keep an eye on particular files. The Azure Functions runtime will cause an app restart to take effect when the contents of the specified files are changed. This is frequently used when changing configuration files or other important files and needing the changes to take effect right away.

**Sample host.json of HttpTrigger:-**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"

  },
  "watchDirectories" : [
    "bin",
    "HttpTrigger1"
  ],
  "watchFiles" : [
    "host.json",
    "local.settings.json"
  ]
  
}
```

This is for monitoring any changes in the HttpTrigger1 and bin directory also host.json, You can access your function directories from Kudu console in ***Development Tools > Advanvced  Tools > Go***

[image]